# Paypal Express Checkout - 400 Bad Request by adding a payee on my payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm testing the express checkout integration using the client side pattern, I have a codepen for that https://codepen.io/vinicio-viaro/pen/XEwywg?editors=1111, doing a normal payment it's working fine, but adding a payee it fails giving 400 bad request error with PERMISSION_DENIED message.

```
transactions: [
                  {
                      amount: { total: '10', currency: 'USD' },
                      payee: {
                            email: 'vinicio-buyer@yopmail.com' // it's business account, I made a mistake labeling as buyer
                      }
                  }
              ]
```

I'm using sandbox accounts, so the one I have as payee it's a business sandbox account, I saw a few posts related to this, but I couldn't found a solution for my error.

To test use:

- user: viniciojoj-buyer @ gmail.com
- pass: testpass

Do I need to enable third-paid payments on someplace? or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t have the buyer (payer) and seller (payee) aa the same email address - as that would mean your paying to yourself.

Even if you as an api caller is different than the payee it would still work - you don’t need 3rd party permissions

I want able to go through the flow without any error are you see this error when the buyer clicks on the button or once they have approved the payment on PayPal.

Comment: Checking github repo I found that is aknow issue, so we have to wait once it gets resolved or move to server side integration:
https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/464